# Capturing video from AppleWatch screen

Tags: ios, apple-watch, quicktime, screen-capture

I was wondering are there any ways to capture the AppleWatch screen.
I'm aware that you can capture iPhone screen with QuickTime screen recoding function, but it's absent for the watch.

Plus, if anyone knows - are there any easy ways to add a watch template to the video?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start your App in the Simulator and use the QuickTime screen recording:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to do it on physical device rather than simulator?

Comment: I'm also looking to record the screen of a physical watch (as requested by an App Store reviewer :/ )

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have a feeling this will be a chronic problem.